# How do I unit test a function that loops over objects?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Let me explain myself.

```
function insertObjects($objs) {
    foreach ($objs as $obj) {
        $this->repository->insert($obj);
    }
}
```

I don't want to test that insertion into the database worked because I assume it works (it's a different unit). I also don't want to test foreach because obviously foreach is going to work. So the only thing to test here is that $objs is a well formed array. But if $objs is the mock data that I will be passing in... so does this mean there is nothing to test for this function?

Comment: I guess repository is a external dependency to `insertObjects` method, so you could test whether `Repository::insert()` method was called _n_ (size of array) times.

Comment: I like the idea of this, but it feels very redundant in practice. If I have an array of n items, and I iterate through them in a foreach loop, then of course it would be called n times. Assuming the constructs (foreach) was a separate unit that has already been unit tested.

Comment: You need to mock `$this->repository`. You should read about [mocking](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) first. If you have further questions I can help

Comment: @hek2mgl I was aware of mocking but I always thought it should be used for third party services. `$this->repository` in this case is my own layer on top of the database. But I suppose mocking could still be used for test for its invocation.

Comment: Mocking is perfectly fine in this situation. Regardless of being 3rd party code or not, everything which does not belong to the *system under test* should/might get mocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's any chance of invalid input (a not well-formed array, null value, etc.), you need to handle that case in your method by explicitly checking for it.

In your test, you would then try to call your method with various invalid values, and check whether your method responds correctly, i.e. the database insert method is not called, exceptions are thrown, errors are logged, etc.

Other than that, the only thing to test is whether your database insert method is called with the parameters that correspond to the values in the valid test array you pass in.

Comment: You are right, I could have a check in the function for the input array. As for testing whether my database insert method is called with the right parameters... how would I test for that in this unit test? It would probably be tested in the unit test for repository insert.

Comment: You need to mock your repository object and check whether the mock is called with the expected values, or not at all, depending on the case (valid or invalid input).

Comment: All details are in [this page](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html). Start reading at the section titled *Mock objects*.